# Dropdown (Select) didn't show default value from the database after update

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot

I have a question about a drowpdown that didn't show the value from the updated table coming from the db.
The list of `value/site_name` of the `table_site` is showed in the drowpdown.
Exemple if i select `"A"` it update `table_y` with the value, but this value is not filled in the dropdown as the default value, the dropdown default value is blank!

What did i miss or did wrong ?

thks for your time/help!

**[file_detail.component.html]**

```
  <div class="flex-cell">
    <app-select *ngIf="siteSelectConfig$ | async as siteSelectConfig"
                [config]="siteSelectConfig"
                (onBlur)="update()">
    </app-select>
  </div>
```

**[app-select / select.component.ts]**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-select',
  templateUrl: './select.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select.component.scss']
})
export class SelectComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() config!: SelectConfig;
  @Output() onBlur = new EventEmitter<void>();

  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit(): void { }
  ngOnChange() { }
}
```

**[file_detail.component.ts]**

```
this.siteService.list().subscribe((list: Site[]) => {
  this.siteList = list;
  this.siteSelectConfig$.next({
    label: {label: 'form.site.label.site_name'},
    placeholder: 'form.site.placeholder.site_name',
    ctrl: this.getControl('site'),
    values: SiteHelper.toSiteOptionArray(list)
  });
})

  public getControl(name: string): FormControl {
    return this.formGroup.get(name) as FormControl;
  }
```

**[select.config.ts]**

```
export interface SelectConfig {
  values: SelectOption[];
  label: LabelWithParam;
  placeholder: string;
  ctrl: FormControl;
}

export interface SelectOption {
  value: any;
  label: string;
}
```

**[select.component.html]**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="config">
  <label>{{config.label.label | translate:config.label.params}}</label>
  <select class="form-control form-control-sm" [formControl]="config.ctrl" (blur)="onBlur.emit()">
    <option disabled>{{'common.select.default' | translate}}</option>
    <option *ngFor="let option of config.values" ngValue="{{option.value}}">{{option.label | translate}}</option>
  </select>
</ng-container>
```

**[site.helper.ts]**

```
  static toSiteOptionArray(list: Site[]): SelectOption[] {
    return list.map((site: Site) => {
      return {value: site.site_id, label: site.name};
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `property binding` when it comes to listening to updates rather than `string interpolation`

```html
 <option 
   *ngFor="let option of config.values" 
   [ngValue]="option.value">{{option.label | translate}}
 </option>
```

Comment: I tested both way [ngValue] or ngValue it didn't change anything, but thanks i leave it with [ngValue]